# Copy one range to another column, then clear the original range

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheets that is updated daily with new inventory data. Currently I have to insert a column, copy and paste the data from A15-50 into C15-50.

Is there any way to insert a column where column C is (shifting data to the right), copy A15-A50 to C15-50 so that yesterday's data goes into a different column (C), and (A) gets cleared out so new data can be input for the day?

Currently I have to have all data cleared from column C or it will paste the data after any data in the column. ie: C15-50 is clear, but C51 has data so the data posts in C52. I am currently copying one cell at a time using:

```
function copypasta() {
var sourceSheet = "Sheet1";
var sourceCell = "B15";
var destinationSheet = "Sheet1";
var destinationCell = "C15"; 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sourceValue = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet).getRange(sourceCell).getValue();
var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheet);

var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destinationCell);

var destRow = destRange.getRow();

var destCol = destRange.getColumn();

var destValues = destSheet.getRange(destRow,destCol,Math.max(1,destSheet.getLastRow()-destRow+1)).getValues();

 for (var i=destValues.length-1;i>=0;--i) {    if (destValues[i]) break;   }
 if (destValues[i]!="") i=i+1;   destSheet.getRange(destRow+i,destCol).setValue(sourceValue);   }
```

then:

```
 function clearOrder() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C15').setValue('');
}
```

Could I change the script to overwrite the data that is in column C?
Is there any way to work on the whole range (C15-50) as opposed to doing it one cell at a time?

I have a little scripting experience but I would consider myself an amateur.

Answer (score 2):

```
var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A15:A50");
var destRange=sourceSheet.getRange("C15:C50"); 
sourceRange.copyTo(destRange);
sourceRange.clearContent();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to insert a column where column C is (shifting data to the right) ?

Yes, there is. From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet

> - insertColumnAfter(afterPosition)
>
>   - Inserts a column after the given column position. insertColumnBefore(beforePosition)
>   - Inserts a column before the given column position.
> - insertColumns(columnIndex)
>
>   - Inserts a blank column in a sheet at the specified location.

---

> Is there any way to work on the whole range (C15-50) as opposed to doing it one cell at a time?

Yes, there is.  From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet

> - getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
>
>   - Returns the range with the top left cell at the given coordinates with the given number of rows and columns.
> - getRange(a1Notation)
>
>   - Returns the range as specified in A1 notation or R1C1 notation.

It's worth to note that getRange(a1Notation) could be a single cell reference or a "multiple cell reference", like `'C15:C50'`.